# Android JsonArray failed to retrieve all the values and display in Listview with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, json, listview

I try to display data that I parse from Json into Listview with SimpleAdapter.

I can display all the data except there is a problem with multiple values in a JsonArray.

[image]

**Json data**

```
{
  "57": {
    "Steak Doness": [
      "well done",
      "medium",
      "rare"
    ]
  },
  "58": {
    "Size": [
      "small",
      "medium",
      "large",
      "extra large"
    ]
  },
  "59": {
    "Cooking Method": [
      "spicy",
      "non-spicy"
    ]
  },
  "63": {
    "Coldness": [
      "with ice",
      "without ice"
    ]
  }
}
```

**java coding**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    String get_option_data=jsonObject.getString("option_data");
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(get_option_data);
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject1.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        String oid = iterator.next();
        String name_value=jsonObject1.getString(oid);
        JSONObject jsonObject2=new JSONObject(name_value);
        Iterator<String> iterator1 = jsonObject2.keys();

        while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
            String name=iterator1.next();
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("oid",oid);
            map.put("name",name);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject2.getJSONArray(name);
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                map.put("value",jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
            aList.add(map);
        }
    }
    String[] from = {"oid","name","value"};
    int[] to = {R.id.oid,R.id.name,R.id.value};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(option.this, aList, R.layout.option_template, from, to);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**As you can see, it only display the last element of JsonArray but not every element in that JsonArray**. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are overriding multiple values on the same position of hashmap. So you have to create either new hashmap for multiple values or pass that all value comma seperated into single key

Your mistake :

```
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        String name=iterator1.next();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("oid",oid);
        map.put("name",name);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject2.getJSONArray(name);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            map.put("value",jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
        aList.add(map);
    }
```

Solution:

```
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        String name=iterator1.next();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("oid",oid);
        map.put("name",name);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject2.getJSONArray(name);
        int i;
        String myValues = "";
        for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            if(myValues.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
               myValues = jsonArray.getString(i);
            else
               myValues = myValues +","+jsonArray.getString(i);
        }
        map.put("value",myValues);
        aList.add(map);
    }
```

In your adpater, You will prase this string and will create new array

```
String[] values = "yourcommaseperatedValue".spilt(",");
```

And display this values array in Textview Like;

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length(); i++){
   yourtextview.setText(values[i]+"\n");
}
```

**Better Approach**

You could take ArrayList to store multiple values but in that case you will have to take new hashmap with type

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Where you will store you unique id "oid" as key and value would be your values jsonArray.

Comment: so far it works fine. all the elements being displayed. Then for "In your adpater, you have to create array by using split(",") and use it."  can you provide coding for this part? As all the values are stick together without a space

Comment: @gosulove : Check it now

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
   map.put("value",jsonArray.getString(i));
}
```

You're replacing both array value with same map key namely `value`. While the loop in action, it's replacing the first value with the later. You can have your array values stored in a list and add the whole list in map.

```
   ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         values.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
   }
   map.put("value", values;
```

All there is left to do is make some minor change in adapter end to show the values from list by iterating it.

Comment: ? I dont get you, so which part of the code should change?

Comment: You're replacing the same `value` key in your map thus, the last value is storing in the map. Wait I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @gosulove Check the answer now.